# Implementando Regex con listas en python

Tags: python

Estoy utilizando regex para buscar ciertos valores y luego borrar palabras en una lista, pero no se me ocurre como eliminarlos de dicha lista. 
El código es el siguiente:

```
import re

lista_precios = ['$2.799','$2.999','$1.999','$1.999','Regular Price$1.715Precio especial$1.200','Regular Price$1.400Precio especial$980','Regular Price$1.899Precio especial$1.329Tan bajo como$1.329','$1.799','Regular Price$1.649Precio especial$1.154',]
for price in lista_precios:
    if re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]',price):
        print(price)

>>Regular Price$1.715Precio especial$1.200
>>Regular Price$1.400Precio especial$980
>>Regular Price$1.899Precio especial$1.329Tan bajo como$1.329
>>Regular Price$1.649Precio especial$1.154
```

Luego de esto, mi idea es eliminar todas las palabras y que muestre solo los precios.
Pensaba hacer algo como:

```
price.remove(r'[a-zA-Z]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré una forma de hacerlo en este post [Python: Extract multiple float numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054733/python-extract-multiple-float-numbers-from-string)

La idea central sería buscar un patrón de la forma `'\d+\.\d+'` donde los dígitos son separados por un punto, mientras el símbolo más (`+`) es para la longitud que pueda tener la parte entera o decimal respectivamente.

Asimismo si bien el código está contemplado para un texto (Párrafo) y en la pregunta se ha proporcionado una lista, sus elementos pueden integrarse usando la función `join`.

En tal sentido la solución quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
lista_precios = ['$2.799','$2.999','$1.999','$1.999',
'Regular Price$1.715Precio especial$1.200',
'Regular Price$1.400Precio especial$980',
'Regular Price$1.899Precio especial$1.329Tan bajo como$1.329',
'$1.799',
'Regular Price$1.649Precio especial$1.154',]

import re

# se concadenas los elementos de la lista con un espacio porque podria
# uno de los elementos terminar en un numero y el otro empezar en un numero entero
s = ' '.join(lista_precios)

# Se captura los patrones flotantes para convertirlos luego en valores
p = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')  

# Se convierte la cadena a flotante
floats = [float(i) for i in p.findall(s)] 

print(*floats, sep='\n')
# 2.799
# 2.999
# 1.999
# 1.999
# 1.715
# 1.2
# 1.4
# 1.899
# 1.329
# 1.329
# 1.799
# 1.649
# 1.154
```